# Do i need to change keyStore jks file after renaming package and application id Android

Tags: android

I recently changed the package name and application id of my android application because when I was uploading the package, google play console thrown an error that example cannot be the package name. So I changed it and now when I install the app in my phone as debug mode then things are working same and properly as expected. Now I created a singed apk and now I have a confusion that do I need a new jks Keystore file or I can proceed with the old one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keystore is used to sign android apps. We can sign as many apps we want. So when I changed the application id and package name, this is now a new app. As I said we can sign many apps. We can sign this app also. So no worries we can proceed.